# array operations facing problem with change in size of array after insertion and after performing one operation loop exit

Tags: c++, arrays, c, data-structures

***header files***
            
   **please help me in fiinding error why my code exits  befor my instruction**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <conio.h>
```

*******display*******

why no of array elements not getting change while traversing array elements all initial no of elements get printed only

```
  int display_array(int arr[], int n)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

***********insertion***********

```
   int insert_position(int arr[], int n)
    {
        int i = 0, pos, num;
        printf("Enter the number to be inserted:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("enter the pposition at which the number is to be inserted:\n");
        scanf("%d", &pos);
        for (i = n - 1; i >= pos; i++)
        {
            arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
        }
        arr[pos] = num;
        n = n + 1;
        return 0;
    }
```

*********deletion*********

```
 int delete_position(int arr[], int n)
    {
        int i = 0, pos;
        printf("Enter the position from which the number has to be deleted:\n");
        scanf("%d", &pos);
    
        for (i = pos; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        }
        n = n - 1;
        return 0;
    }
```

**driver program**

Comment: Since you don't validate the values of either `pos` or `num` and there is no way to tell if you require 0-based or 1-based `pos` and `num`, there is now way to give a concrete answer. Though your use of both `pos` and `num` can attempt access below `0` and above `n`. Validate EVERY user-input, (e.g. `if (scanf ("%d", &pos) != 1) { /* handle error */ }`) and validate each input is within the required range (e.g. `if (pos < 0 || n <= pos) { /* handle invalid pos * }`)

Comment: Also, don't use the ancient DOS header `conio.h`. If you need to hold the terminal open on windows, just use `getchar()`. `conio.h` is 100% non-portable to anything but DOS or windows.

Comment: I am not sure `#include<conio.h>` still in use, better to use latest compilers

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing those parameters in these functions as pass by value, not **pass by reference**. That's why initial values are printing every time you are calling them.
You can use pointers, or you can use global variables to get the desired result.